# Is it possible to add a fade to the .slideUp & .slideDown jQuery Function

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, slidedown, slideup

Is it possible to have a slight fade to the .slideUp & .slideDown so it slides upwards with a fade?

```
options.trickerPanel.slideUp(function() {
        $(this).html(value).slideDown();
```

Here is the full code for example http://jsfiddle.net/LtpHv/1/

Comment: see if you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/LtpHv/2/

Comment: I don't think there are any current implementations of what you want to do. You could try putting a gradient .png (50% transparent, 50% bg color) at the bottom of the element. When it slides up, the bottom will appear as if its fading

Comment: @BillyMathews How would you add that into the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).html(value).css('opacity', 0)
  .slideDown('slow')
  .animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/LtpHv/6/)**

Comment: How would you make the .slideUp fadeOut?

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with a simple sequential fade + slide?

```
$('#a').fadeOut();
$('#a').slideUp();
```

Both actions will take place at the same time giving you a nice fade + slide effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a number in the SlideDown function, this is the time in milliseconds that it takes for the animation to take place.

```
slideDown("Enter number here")
slideUp("Enter number here", function(){ }
```

I have made the changes in your fiddle

Sample code http://jsfiddle.net/LtpHv/5/